# After replacing my modem/router I am no longer able to access an internal git server locally, but still can from external networks

Tags: git, ssh, portforwarding

I have a git 'user' account established on a local machine.  I was able to use it with git clone git@localhost:repo/gitrep.git from both the local area network and from externally as git clone git@domain.com:repo/gitrep.git, where domain.com is a domain name maintained by Dyndns.  I had to change my internet modem/router and after port forwarding domain.com access to ports 22, 443, 80, 3036 and 8080, as it was on the older router, I can access my server from an external network, but not from a machine on the internal network.  I can ping it, ssh to the git users account, but git will not connect.  What do I need to check to determine the problem?

Comment: We will need more information. How does it fail? Does it hang? Can you run the sshd in debug mode? Try to collect some data.
Was the router also responsible for assigning ip addresses on your local network?  Did it assign a new ip address?

Comment: It just hangs.  ssh -v works fine.  It's the git ssh that is failing internally.  Initially I had a static ip and use port forwarding to that static ip, but the new modem doesn't allow that.  I get the ip from DHCP and the router says it is a reserved port and forwards to it.  But only from externally.

Comment: You did not mention authentication. SSH keys? Do you use any special s/w to manage keys and access?

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/336907/really-verbose-way-to-test-git-connection-over-ssh

Comment: Git itself literally just runs `ssh` (to make any ssh-authenticated connection). So if ssh works, so should Git. This is rather a puzzle, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my isp had implemented a new 'security' feature on the new modem/router that when it detected 'suspicious' activity, it blocked the port.  The suspicious activity was my using ssh to access another machine on my local network.  I turned off that 'security' feature and now everything works fine.